# There is something wrong with my CURL script

Tags: php, curl

I'm using a CURL script to basically recreate the process a user having to hit send on a form. I would like everything to run in the background but it never sends when this script executes.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "&shopId=".$ID."&encodedMessage=".urlencode($encodedMessage)."&signature=".$signature);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Is it perhaps not executing?

Comment: If curl's failing, the exec() call will return a boolean fase. so add a `if ($result === FALSE) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` after the exec call. That'll kill the script and output the last curl error.

Answer (score 1):

Tested, working great.

Did you set the variable `$url` right?

Comment: Yes I have set it. is this the executing part?    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: That's the executing part. You should always handle errors in live code, so check if `$result === false` and also `curl_geterrno($ch)`. You might find helpful information in `curl_getinfo($ch)`, like whether the result was a 404 or something. You also need to `curl_close($ch)` once you're done with it to make sure you don't have too many sockets open.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. But if the code is sending fine then it's not my issue. It sounds like the programmer who is receiving the code is having an issue. Is there a way to test if cURL is working on my server?

Comment: You can `print $result;` after the curl_exec() line if you wanna check what does it return.

Answer (score 0):

curl is not a good option to emulate fork.

As soon as your current script stops, the curl request will be killed and probably the target url will also stop executing its own script.

you could use a cron or similar external process to run the curl requests and it would run with no interruption. It would also be helpful to queue up parallel requests.